# How should we deal with "offensive" language that might not be such from a non-native speaker?

Tags: discussion, non-english-speakers

In a weak answer to this [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/how-to-make-custom-cards-against-humanity-cards/15587#15587), the answerer referred to "molesting" cards.

In an English language context, I would find that offensive. But I get the sense that the answerer may be a native Spanish, rather than English speaker. I also know that in Spanish, "molestar" means to disturb, which really isn't a "bad word" in that language.

What should we do about posts that may "sound bad" in English, but perhaps wasn't meant in a bad way by a non-native English speaker?

In this case, I flagged a moderator for possible deletion of the post because of its overall weakness. But if had been a strong post, I might have tried fixing it, instead. Should we give people the benefit of the doubt in these language situations?

Comment: Just fix it?​​​

Comment: Since the "offensive" part is innocent mistake done as result of language barrier, this discussion is the same as the general "How can we improve the experience for non-native speakers" one.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I don't consider this a duplicate because  it's not about the garden variety low-quality question based on the "experience" of non-native speakers, but rather the fact that they may occasionally use words that are offensive or "swear" words in English, that might not be such in their native language. Put another way, should we "flag" them, or use other means of dealing with them.

Comment: Just edit them out and explain to the OP what you did.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: OK, fair enough.

Comment: Just my two cents: I think "molest" was actually a good word for expressing the meaning they intended.